# how to use onClick handler in mapping item? (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm student studying of react.
While working on the project, I had a question.

```
{pages.map((page, idx) => (
  <li key={page.page_id} id={`${idx + 1}`} css={CSSCarouselItem}>
    <Photo onClick={() => console.log('click!')}/>
    <p css={CSSPageContent}>{page.text}</p>
........
  </li>
))}
```

and Photo components

```
interface PhotoProps {
.....
  onClick?: () => void;
}


const Photo = ({ src, width, height, blur, custom, onClick, text, placeholder }: PhotoProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={onClick}>
    ... 
    </div>
```

I have to apply onClick handler **only to Photo components.**
However, onClick applies only to the highest element(li components) that is mapped.
photo's onClick doesn't work.
Is this inevitable?

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: From your code the onClick handler should only apply to the Photo component, are you sure this is the right code and that this behavior is still happening?

Comment: Yes It's still the same. 

Answer (score 0):

No, you can apply the onClick handler to the specific component within the mapped element. To do that, you can simply pass the onClick handler to the Photo component inside the li element:

```
{pages.map((page, idx) => (
  <li key={page.page_id} id={`${idx + 1}`} css={CSSCarouselItem}>
    <Photo onClick={() => { /* your onClick handler here */ }} />
    <p css={CSSPageContent}>{page.text}</p>
........
  </li>
))}
```

This way, the onClick handler will be passed to it, and inside component you can apply this on it's parent component. And it can be triggered when the Photo component is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for you answer !!

I also set up the Photo component to receive onClick prop. And I clicked on, but it doesn't apply because the click event didn't go over at all.

OnClick only applies normally to the highest li component. But I have to be able to press only sub-photo.

I did as I explained and checked everything. However, I have a headache because the onClick event is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

Add onClick func as prop in Photo component.

```
{pages.map((page, idx) => (
  <li key={page.page_id} id={`${idx + 1}`} css={CSSCarouselItem}>
    <Photo onClick=(() => {/* your click func */})/>
    <p css={CSSPageContent}>{page.text}</p>
........
  </li>
))}
```

And add the attribute for your img (or what you have there)

```
function Photo({onClick}) {
   <img onClick={onClick}/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer !! I also set up the Photo component to receive onClick prop. And I clicked on, but it doesn't apply because the click event didn't go over at all. OnClick only applies normally to the highest li component. But I have to be able to press only sub-photo. I did as I explained and checked everything. However, I have a headache because the onClick event is not applied.